# Prevent JPopup from going behind without the need for AlwaysOnTop()

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I have a dialog that will open another dialog, is there anyway to keep the opened dialog on top of the main dialog without setting always on top? Example:

```
JPopupDialog mainDialog = new JPopupDialog("Main"){

    JButton b = new JButton();
    b.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            JPopupDialog subDialog = new JPopupDialog("Sub"){
            
            }
            subDialog.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
    mainDialog.add(b);
    mainDialog.setVisible(true);
}
```

Is it possible to keep sub dialog always on top of main dialog, BUT not set he always on top flag, as i still need to interact with a base layer.

Comment: "_BUT not set he always on top flag, as i still need to interact with a base layer._" - Can you explain in more detail what exact behavior you want to avoid, and how the dialogs are supposed to behave? Because, if you want to "_interact with a base layer_", then I suppose a `JDialog` is not what you want.

Comment: [Edit] to add a [mre].

Comment: 1) use a non-modal JDialog then you will have access to the parent window 2) specify the parent window when you create the dialog.